# How to check movieClips is visible under mask

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, actionscript-2, mask

This was something I looked at a while back but couldn't figure it out. Now returning to give it another go.

Basically I want to find out how to check if a movieclip is visible under a mask.
I've got a row of thumbs in a movieclip under a mask. Some are out with the the masked area so I've got some script to make the movieclip scroll the other thumbs into view of the masked area. Is there any code I can apply to the thumbs to check if they are in or not in view of the masked area?
Any help or insight would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Could you post a demo of your current application? It's a bit hard to visualize the problem. It sounds like it could be trivial; simply compare the position of the mask with the position of the thumbs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Rectangle intersection check to see if the bounds of the mask intersects with the bounds of the thumbs.

```
var maskBounds : Rectangle = myMask.getBounds(this);
var thumb : MovieClip;
var thumbBounds : Rectangle;

for(var i : int = 0 ; i < _thumbs.length ; i++)
{
    thumb = _thumbs[i];
    thumbBounds = thumb.getBounds(this);

    if(maskBounds.intersects(thumbBounds))
    {
        trace(i, "in view");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you Mattias that's pretty much what I was looking for.